# How can I specify a pointer as a parameter to a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, types

I'm trying to define a function (*initdeque()*) that takes a pointer to an instance of the deque class. So this is what I tried:

```
from ctypes import *

class deque(Structure):
        pass

deque._fields_ = [("left",POINTER(node)),("right",POINTER(node))]

def initdeque(class deque *p):
        p.left=p.right=None
```

But this code gives a syntax error:

```
  def initdeque(class deque *p):
                      ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: what do you want to do with this ? create a `deque` class implemented in C ?

Comment: ctypes is most definitely not the way to learn Python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to specify the type of Python variables, so the declaration of `initdequeue` should just say:

```
def initdeque(p):
  p.left = p.right = None
```

Instead of having a random function doing the initialization, you should consider using an [initializer](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__):

```
class deque(Structure):
  _fields_ = [("left",POINTER(node)), ("right",POINTER(node))]

  def __init__(self):
    self.left = self.right = None
```

Now, to create a new instance, just write

```
 p = dequeue()
```

Comment: sir, but does this "p" become an instance of the deque class??

Comment: @kiran No. The type of an object is fixed when it's constructed. Python prefers [duck typing](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing) over static typing.

Comment: what's more, __fields__ should be defined in the class rather than outside

Comment: My question is how can i receive such an instance as an argument?

Comment: @kiran You just write a method that operates on an object of any type, and pass in an object with the "right"(or a compatible) type. By the way, a single question mark is sufficient.

Comment: @David Heffernan fields defined inside gives the error "dequeue not defined"

Comment: @kiran Amended my second example with the correct way to put `__fields__` inside. Everything in a class body is assigned to the class.

Comment: @kiran I urge you to reconsider learning Python via ctypes. The result will be poor knowledge of both.

Comment: @David Heffernan It's just for an assignment. What i love with python is it's simplicity, after this adieu to ctypes.. :)

Comment: @kiran That's because you're using `POINTER(dequeue)`, not `POINTER(node)`. If you want the former, you'll have to define `__fields__` afterwards indeed. Note that as David said, ctypes is an extremely unusual Python module, you should start with plain Python first before using it.

Comment: @phihag i understand that it is because of POINTER(deque). What i need is pointers to the same class deque inside the class , not the pointers to a class node.

Comment: @kiran I speak from experience. I learnt Python with ctypes and am still trying to recover.

Comment: @phihag yes,i have been learning from the python documentation.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Python (like Matlab) does not have explicit variable type definition. When a variable is created the compiler defines it's type judging from it's content. So (if I am not wrong) you can call the same function with multiple types as parameters and still work. 
For example

```
def fun(p):
       return p=p*5
```

So u can call fun with a string as a parameter and return you a string that contains 5 times the string you sent. Or you can call it with an integer and the function will return you the result of the multiplication